# Drawing 2D boxplots with R (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have grouped data with, say, 2 parameters:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame( xx=sample(10,9),
                   yy=sample(20,9),
                   group=c('A','B', 'C')  )
```

I can draw boxplots for each dimension:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=group, y=yy, fill=group)) + geom_boxplot() 
ggplot(dat, aes(x=group, y=xx, fill=group)) + geom_boxplot() + coord_flip()
```

[image]

Now I would to combine these and draw boxplots reflecting data on both variables, something like this:
 [image]
(this image was made manually in graphic editor)

Is there any easy way to draw this kind of boxplots?

Answer (score 0):

That is not good way of representation. It can be very confusing. Usually that data is represented like this.

```
datPlot <- melt(dat)
ggplot(datPlot, aes(x=group, y=value, fill=variable)) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

or if the range of two variables is very different you can try faceting

```
ggplot(datPlot, aes(x=group, y=value, fill=group)) + geom_boxplot()
 +facet_wrap(~variable,scale="free_y")
```

[image]

or this

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=xx, y=yy, color=group)) + geom_point(size=3)
```

[image]

Comment: on your first representation you assume that x and y are of the same scale, which is generally not the case (my bad, I should have included this in my example - put something like `yy=sample(2e5,9)`). Your second representation is just a scatterplot, i.e. we totally loose all advantages of the boxplot...

Comment: Then i guess the only way it could be done is precalculating quantiles of both variables and plot using geom_polygon. I will try and get back.

Comment: There are bivariate extensions to boxplots, see this [cross validated thread](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/54504/1036).