# How to make a 2d boxplot out of matrix data format in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've recently been using R for some graphs and I came up with the following data in csv

```
ID,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,5a,6a,7a,9a,12a,15a
1,435,269,994,832,637,2931,3275,1690,5228,1951,2312,2336,2029,3796,2698,22814,618,752,888,1810,927
2,805,522,862,972,970,1332,1409,2236,1710,3130,2096,2775,4325,4462,8057,3358,826,1118,1181,1542,1681
3,702,656,755,1393,1881,1433,3700,2163,2849,2143,3958,3529,4171,4152,12918,1528,1051,2377,1988,2173,3904
4,833,791,2398,920,0,3200,1850,5038,2626,3854,6144,5505,6861,6860,5002,5383,53,1398,1473,2422,161
5,1635,1783,4765,1768,2130,5761,2114,10518,2732,5109,8508,7307,5910,6825,6605,4430,2020,1879,1663,6087,2735
.
.
.
```

How can I make a 2d boxplot out of this data, given that my X data label should be each column besides ID (that be: 1,2,3,4,5....,15a) and each "box" the values in each column divided by 1000?

I figured a way from the documentation to plot this in a 2d boxplot only if my data is also 2 dimensional, but in this case I have 21 columns.

I could do this by transforming the dataset, but this csv file is updated daily, so it can get tiresome.

I've done this in Python (Xlabel = 1,2,3,4..,15 only) and gave me this following result (the value in label "4" is wrong though):

[image: desired output]

Comment: You can lookup at the below link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30072525/drawing-2d-boxplots Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to melt to long form so you have single x and y variables. Using Hadleyverse packages:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

       # melt from wide to long
df %>% gather(x, y, -ID) %>% 
           # scale y as described
    mutate(y = y / 1000, 
           # clean out letters inserted by read.csv
           x = substr(x, 2, nchar(x)), 
           # fix factor level order so x axis will be in correct order
           x = factor(x, levels = unique(x[order(extract_numeric(x))]))) %>% 
    # plot
    ggplot(aes(x, y)) + 
        geom_boxplot()
```

[image: boxplot]

---

#### Data

```
df <- read.csv(text = 'ID,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,5a,6a,7a,9a,12a,15a
         1,435,269,994,832,637,2931,3275,1690,5228,1951,2312,2336,2029,3796,2698,22814,618,752,888,1810,927
         2,805,522,862,972,970,1332,1409,2236,1710,3130,2096,2775,4325,4462,8057,3358,826,1118,1181,1542,1681
         3,702,656,755,1393,1881,1433,3700,2163,2849,2143,3958,3529,4171,4152,12918,1528,1051,2377,1988,2173,3904
         4,833,791,2398,920,0,3200,1850,5038,2626,3854,6144,5505,6861,6860,5002,5383,53,1398,1473,2422,161
         5,1635,1783,4765,1768,2130,5761,2114,10518,2732,5109,8508,7307,5910,6825,6605,4430,2020,1879,1663,6087,2735')
```